# Canvas not supported by browser when using GoJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, gojs

I'm using GoJS and trying to setup a simple diagram on page using:

```
 const $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates
const myDiagram =
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // create a Diagram for the DIV HTML element
    { // enable undo & redo
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true
    });

// define a simple Node template
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the Shape will go around the TextBlock
    $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
      { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "white" },  // default fill is white
      // Shape.fill is bound to Node.data.color
      new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      { margin: 8 },  // some room around the text
      // TextBlock.text is bound to Node.data.key
      new go.Binding("text", "key"))
  );

// but use the default Link template, by not setting Diagram.linkTemplate

// create the model data that will be represented by Nodes and Links
myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[
  { key: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
  { key: "Beta", color: "orange" },
  { key: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
  { key: "Delta", color: "pink" }
],
[
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Beta" },
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Gamma" },
  { from: "Beta", to: "Beta" },
  { from: "Gamma", to: "Delta" },
  { from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" }
]);
```

And when rendered I have:

> This text is displayed if your browser does not support the Canvas HTML element.

Inside canvas tag. That's very odd since I have the latest vesrion of Chrome, Firefox and Edge (I tried them all) and they support canvas.
And using simple canvas with simple shapes without GoJS renders correct result.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's the right behaviour of canvas HTML element, not GoJS problem.

As [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) said, the canvas element is "used to draw graphics on a web page". You cannot inspect elements in it.

If you want to inspect nodes and links from GoJS diagram, you can type `diagram.model.nodeDataArray` or `diagram.model.linkDataArray` to browser console.